# How to clear an interval if my config file sets it to off

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to make a bot clear an interval if my config file says "off" but leave it running if it says "on".

I've already tried doing

discord.js

```
    config.Interval = setInterval(() => {
        WallCheck.send(WallCheckembed);
    }, 500);

    clearInterval(off)
};
```

but when I put in the "config.Interval" its setting the setInterval to "config.Interval".

discord.js

```
    config.Interval = setInterval(() => {
        WallCheck.send(WallCheckembed);
    }, 500);
```

This is my code. And my config file is:

```
"Interval": "off"
```

The only error I'm getting is this:

```
(node:6844) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: off is not defined
```

And the variable "off" is referring to the "off" in my clear interval.

Comment: `And the variable "off" is referring to the "off" in my clear interval.` You don't have an `off` defined.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow ! 
When clearing an interval, you need to pass the variable created by the setInterval.:

```
var count = 0;
var myInterval = setInterval(()=> {
    // i do somehting every 5 second
    if(count >= 10) {
        // we can access variable outside the callback because we are using the arrow operator.
        clearInterval(myInterval)
    }
    count++;
}, 5000);
```